# Parenthesis-like effect for sparse tree queries

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to define queries for sparse trees that combine different conditions, for instance.

- (`DEADLINE` or `SCHEDULED` closer to one year), **and**
- (`TODO` keyword is `NEXT` or `TODO` or `WAITING`, **or** tagged as unplanned) **and**
- ...

This is in a normal buffer, not the agenda buffer. I do not need this in the agenda buffer.

This would be very easy to do if parenthesis were allowed in sparse tree queries, but they are not implemented.

I need to do this with many conditions. If I distribute conditions over, the number of combinations I'd need to write grows far too quickly and it becomes impractical.

A "solution" would be to apply an `org-match-sparse-tree` on the result of another, somehow nesting conditions.

Is this possible? If not, are there alternatives to solve the problem I'm trying to solve?

How much effort would it take to implement parenthesis in search, or cummulative filtering and searching in sparse trees?

EDIT: bounty, hence changing the "goal" of the question.

Comment: The problem with `org-make-tags-matcher` is that it is not a proper parser-interpreter pair. For an instance it splits `MATCH` at `|` and afterwards repairs such splits if the `|` is actually escaped by `\ `. Something like that should not be necessary with a proper parser. If the parser and the code generator/interpreter would be built with `wisent` then the addition of parenthesis to the syntax would be no problem. That would mean a re-write of `org-make-tags-matcher`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Roughly, how much work would that take?

Comment: One (hacky) approach would be (1st) to parse the `MATCH` (extended with parentheses) into an abstract syntax tree `AST` with the help of a wisent-generated parser (should be relatively simple), (2nd) to apply the distribution law to the AST, and (3rd) to print the transformed AST out into a string that is used as argument to `org-make-tags-matcher`. The string does not have any parenthesis anymore and is therefore suitable for `org-make-tags-matcher`.

Comment: All those tasks I described in my previous comment should be relatively simple experience with wisent and elisp assumed.

Comment: Note that my experience with Wisent is limited but I think that `wisent-calc.wy` would be a good starting point for that adventure.

Comment: Well I don't have the skills myself, but I'd be happy to put a small monetary bounty to at least feed a developer a couple of pizzas and a beer, for implementing this correctly and getting it into org-mode so that it benefits everybody :)

Comment: (I would obviously prefer that org-make-tags-matcher be implemented with parenthesis handling irself, but for that it needs to properly parse the string into an AST as well and probably perform the filtering in a different way.)

Comment: So if I understand your request, you're trying to perform an incremental search on an org-file's keywords, properties, and tags on a given org-file? Sort of like helm-ag, but robust enough to increment matching query-strings to entire headers instead of just lines?

Comment: It's not an incremental search. It's a sparse tree. The language is more expressive than keywords and tags (I don't know if SCHEDULED, for instance, is considered a property or something else). I'm not sure SCHEDULED is part of the header either.